# How to swap one coin to another in Web3.py using Uniswap contracts?

Tags: uniswap, web3.py, python, exchanges, router

I want to make an exchange from MATIC in order to get USDC.

I'm using [Infura](https://app.infura.io/) web3-RpcUrl. I'm open to use any router contract like swap, 1inch, uniswap, sushiswap etc.

My code partially works, as I'm able to send funds in MATIC, but the USDC tokens are not being received in exchange, when using the **Uniswap contract**.

Here is the code:

```
import time
from web3 import Web3

class swapExample():
    def __init__(self, wallet: str, private_key: str, web3RpcUrl: str, 
        buy_amount: int, from_token: str, to_token: str, rourter_adress: str, abi: str):
        
        #Setup Wallet Informations and RPC
        #Usually we place these info in separate .env or .py or .json file.
        self.wallet = Web3.to_checksum_address(wallet) #your wallet address
        self.pk = private_key #your wallet private key
        self.rpc = web3RpcUrl #your node or use public rpc
        self.web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(self.rpc)) #connect to web3

        #Setup Swap Value / Gas limit / Gwei
        #Change these values if you want.
        self.buy_amount = buy_amount #Ether value to spend
        self.gas = 500000 #gas limit
        self.gwei = 200  #gwei

        #Setup WETH token address (to spend) and Token address (to buy)
        #In my case I'll use WBNB to buy Safemoon token (at BSC Testnet)
        self.WETH = self.web3.to_checksum_address(from_token)
        self.token_to_buy = self.web3.to_checksum_address(to_token)

        #Setup router address (Sushiswap Router Address)
        #In my case I'll use Pancakeswap Router (at BSC Testnet)
        self.router = self.web3.to_checksum_address(rourter_adress)

        #Setup SwapExactETHforTokens ABI
        #You can get this ABI directly from Verified Contract Source Code at Etherscan
        self.abi = abi

        #Creating instance.
        #We can call contract functions with this.
        self.router_contract = self.web3.eth.contract(address=self.router, abi=self.abi)

        # #Do swap.
        # self.swap()

    #From here we are going to create Swap function.
    def swap(self):
        #building transaction with swap parameters
        #you can edit this if you want
        swap_txn = self.router_contract.functions.exactInputSingle(
            {
                'tokenIn': self.WETH, # Адрес токена MATIC
                'tokenOut': self.token_to_buy, # Адрес токена USDC
                'fee': 3000, # Комиссия за операцию (0.3%)
                'recipient': self.wallet, # Ваш кошелек для получения токенов
                'deadline': int(time.time()) + 10000, # Дедлайн
                'amountIn': self.web3.to_wei(self.buy_amount, 'ether'), # Количество MATIC для обмена
                'amountOutMinimum': 0, # Минимальное количество USDC для получения (0 для любого количества)
                'sqrtPriceLimitX96': 0 # 0 для любого курса обмена
            }
        ).build_transaction({
            'from': self.wallet,
            'gas': self.gas,
            'gasPrice': self.web3.to_wei(self.gwei, 'gwei'),
            'nonce': self.web3.eth.get_transaction_count(self.wallet),
        })

        #Sign swap tx and send to blockchain
        sign_tx = self.web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(swap_txn, private_key=self.pk)
        buy_tx = self.web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(sign_tx.rawTransaction)
        print("Txn sent, awaiting for response.")
    
        #Await for result
        tx_result = self.web3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(buy_tx) 

        # Transaction status verification
        # If status == 1: Swap success.
        if tx_result['status'] == 1: 
            print("Success! TX:", self.web3.to_hex(buy_tx))
            return True 
        else: 
            print("Error! TX:", self.web3.to_hex(buy_tx))
            return False

init = swapExample(
    wallet='walet',
    private_key='privat key', 
    web3RpcUrl='https://polygon-mainnet.infura.io/v3/here_code',
    buy_amount=0.0001,
    from_token='0x0d500B1d8E8eF31E21C99d1Db9A6444d3ADf1270',
    to_token='0x2791Bca1f2de4661ED88A30C99A7a9449Aa84174',
    rourter_adress='0xa5E0829CaCEd8fFDD4De3c43696c57F7D7A678ff',
    abi= '[{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_factory","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"_WETH9","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"inputs":[],"name":"WETH9","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"components":[{"internalType":"bytes","name":"path","type":"bytes"},{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMinimum","type":"uint256"}],"internalType":"struct ISwapRouter.ExactInputParams","name":"params","type":"tuple"}],"name":"exactInput","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"components":[{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenIn","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenOut","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint24","name":"fee","type":"uint24"},{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMinimum","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint160","name":"sqrtPriceLimitX96","type":"uint160"}],"internalType":"struct ISwapRouter.ExactInputSingleParams","name":"params","type":"tuple"}],"name":"exactInputSingle","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"components":[{"internalType":"bytes","name":"path","type":"bytes"},{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountInMaximum","type":"uint256"}],"internalType":"struct ISwapRouter.ExactOutputParams","name":"params","type":"tuple"}],"name":"exactOutput","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"components":[{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenIn","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenOut","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint24","name":"fee","type":"uint24"},{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountInMaximum","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint160","name":"sqrtPriceLimitX96","type":"uint160"}],"internalType":"struct ISwapRouter.ExactOutputSingleParams","name":"params","type":"tuple"}],"name":"exactOutputSingle","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"factory","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes[]","name":"data","type":"bytes[]"}],"name":"multicall","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes[]","name":"results","type":"bytes[]"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"refundETH","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"value","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"v","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"r","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"s","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"selfPermit","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"nonce","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"expiry","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"v","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"r","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"s","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"selfPermitAllowed","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"nonce","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"expiry","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"v","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"r","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"s","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"selfPermitAllowedIfNecessary","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"value","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"v","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"r","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"s","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"selfPermitIfNecessary","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountMinimum","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"}],"name":"sweepToken","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountMinimum","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"feeBips","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"feeRecipient","type":"address"}],"name":"sweepTokenWithFee","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"int256","name":"amount0Delta","type":"int256"},{"internalType":"int256","name":"amount1Delta","type":"int256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"_data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"uniswapV3SwapCallback","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountMinimum","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"}],"name":"unwrapWETH9","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountMinimum","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"feeBips","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"feeRecipient","type":"address"}],"name":"unwrapWETH9WithFee","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"stateMutability":"payable","type":"receive"}]'
    )

init.swap()
```

So, how to correctly configure the parameters like `rourter_adress`, `abi`, `from_token`, `to_token`, etc. in order to make it working ?

Comment: You're using this [QuickSwap: Router](https://polygonscan.com/address/0xa5E0829CaCEd8fFDD4De3c43696c57F7D7A678ff) contract on **Polygon mainnet**, right? But, it seems to be having a different set of functions (i.e., different ABI).

Comment: Which one should I use? Please tell me.

Comment: I guess, the **router_address** should be [0xE592427A0AEce92De3Edee1F18E0157C05861564](https://polygonscan.com/address/0xE592427A0AEce92De3Edee1F18E0157C05861564). But, I would recommend you to try on testnet first, as [Uniswap contracts](https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v3/reference/deployments#sepolia-addresses) are available on Sepolia testnet as well.

Comment: [You can find example how to do swap in Uniswap using Python here](https://web3-ethereum-defi.readthedocs.io/tutorials/make-uniswap-swap-in-python.html)